# Need to replace a space/tab/line skip with some charaters like ',' in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file like below

```
10039
10306
10307
10308
10730
10731
10737
10738
10739
```

and I need to replace it in Notepad++ to be like below to be used as SQL code

```
10039','10306','10307','10308','10730','10731','10737'
```

Comment: the file is actual numbers separated with line skip 10039
10306
10307
10308
10730
10731
10737
10738

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\d+)(?:(\R)|\z)`
- Replace with: `'$1'(?2,:)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\d+)       # group 1, 1 or more digits
(?:         # non capture group
    (\R)    # group 2, any kind of linebreak
  |         # OR
    \z      # end of file
)           # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
'$1'        # content of group 1, with single quotes around
(?2         # if group 2  exists
    ,       # a comma
    :       # else
            # nothing
)           # endif
```

**Result for given example:**

```
'10039','10306','10307','10308','10730','10731','10737','10738','10739'
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I have already solved as below using simple functions:          1. Edit/Blank Operation/Remove unnecessary Blank and EOL
2. Search/ Replace “pure tab space” with whatever character you need to insert

Comment: @jean: Nice but I'm wondering how you can have a single quote at the beginning and at the end with these 2 operations only. You should answer you own question to show people how you have solved this.

Comment: hello, I haven't used any operation, expression or code ; first part was a simple function from the menu (1. Edit/Blank Operation/Remove unnecessary Blank and EOL) and the second part is the simple "Replace" function from the menu as well (2. Search/ Replace blank with ',' ). Actually the blank/tab/space is replaced by the following ','

Comment: @jean: I see, but this is not adding a quote at the beginning and at the end of the string.